# Via for 50 Ohm impedence track to U.FL connector

Tags: pcb-design, impedance-matching, via

There's a 4G LTE modem along with GNSS capability mounted on the bottom layer of a 4 layer PCB. Its a 4 layer PCB with [JLC04161H-7628 Stackup](https://jlcpcb.com/impedance). 50 Ohm impedance trace needs to go to U.FL connectors on the top layer of the PCB through a via for both the LTE and GPS signals. How to design the signal via and stitching vias around it to achieve this?

Comment: [Via impedance calculator](https://designertools.app.protoexpress.com/?appid=VIAIMPCAL&data=ONsTAS5bIR5nFHqIuoQIEqpeYI6FNtC1kNPK9gKk14INuL5nZePBvOxvbHPnk5%20cnHE%20LdwaQf3NPMrsZsHzKD%20%2FM7rjI1AL7TaRuIf%20k%2FaLF5w5yX8NdWEca2p4jr%2Fqd%2F3jiCq2vt109mcdP9itFqb25bcJfU80I08FAEkspybHJoOJbTfc%2FCoK4ZEe1vozrLfjq9Dfs2X42lXYJUnGyJi%20eJFcIvDOZINfUJtZF81UttQPqGh3kPEVQTVWItcA67vr3TNP%20WeEN22%20bXT7AER4Z2z2hsmst3QN4FxVwxvTJQoSn0PzSIu7GDixipPk0cwhm3SBk3Vu9L4HLMaXYQ%3D%3D&q=Fri%20Mar%2003%2004:53:14%20PST%202023)

Comment: Thanks Andy. https://resources.altium.com/p/why-most-via-impedance-calculators-are-inaccurate this article mentions stitching vias are important. Also the dependence of frequency for calculating the impedance. The calculator you shared doesn't account for these. Thought?